# Transferred Domain DNS to Amazon AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am attempting to route inbound email to an EC2 instance.  I am able to get the process to work from one domain, but not the other.  This could be a problem w/ propagation/DNS cache delays but, just in case, I thought it might be wise to share my setup w/ the SO community.

Domain (popadvantage.com) is registered through GoDaddy.  Note that name servers are pointed to the Route53 NS records.

[image: Domain registration]

The domain is set as a Hosted Zone in Route 53 and all DNS records have been entered for several hours.  Screenshot:

[image: Route 53 configuration]

I must be doing something wrong.  I've been at this rollout for 16 hours so, the way my eyes are seeing things right now, I might just be missing something simple.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this 10 minutes later.  It's amazing how writing something down jobs the mind to go double-check something you've otherwise overlooked.

IN case it helps anyone else, the answer was that each "hosted zone" in Route53 has its own nameservers.  To those of you who are intimately familiar w/ Route53, that's probably common sense.  I'm brand new to Route53 (today actually) so I didn't know that.  I think that's great actually and I applaud them for their ingenuity and creativity and the redundancy of their nameserver setup.

Coming from a networking background, I just overlook this because every DNS host I've ever used has either had static nameserver domains or assigned static nameserver domains to each account.  I never thought that each domain could/would have different nameservers.  It does actually make for some more clicks and copy/pastes when you're dealing w/ moving hundreds of domain names from one place to Route53 when you've got to get 4 new nameservers per domain after adding the domain as a hosted zone, but I'm sure AWS has pretty good reasons for doing ti this way that outweigh the extra work on the front.

I loathe answering my own question - it feel so much like playing a game by yourself, like throwing a football straight up to catch it yourself only a few steps later.  I'm not even sure anyone will ever read this.

Comment: They have several good reasons for doing it this way: the algorithm that assigns each new hosted zone its 4 name servers is designed to never assign more than 2 of the same servers to any 2 of your domains.  So if just the right set of 4 servers failed, a maximum of 1 of your hosted zones would experience an outage.  You can, however, create a [reusable delegation set](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/white-label-name-servers.html) and deliberately defeat this mechanism, if you're so inclined, by creating some of your hosted zones all on the same 4 Route 53 servers.

Comment: Also, this setup allows you, from a different AWS account, to create the same hosted zone, and then migrate to it, by changing the name servers with the registrar... or even to create a duplicate hosted zone in your same AWS account if you had a reason to do that, and migrate.  Or, I can create a hosted zone for your domain, accidentally or maliciously, and it will never interfere with your genuine records, since my records will be sitting out on 4 unrelated servers that will never actually be queried.